# Conditional counts and applying WHERE clauses to them

Tags: sql, hive, conditional-statements, aggregation, presto

Apologies if the title is a little off, I wasn't quite sure how to succinctly explain what I'm trying to do.

I have a table that stores individual web requests to a server, for the purposes of this question I will omit all columns except for the following - **request_id (int), app_name (string), sdk_version (string)**. My web-server exposes an API for app developers to use, it is normal to receive many requests from a single app_name but with a variety of sdk_versions since not all users will use the most recent version of our SDK.

So the table may look a little like this:

```
request_id | app_name | sdk_version
001         App1        1            
002         App1        1   
003         App1        2
004         App2        2
005         App2        3
```

I want to write a query that will return a list of apps and the number of requests that come from each version of our SDK, I'd effectively need to count the rows in the table. Something like the following:

```
app_name | sdk_version_1 | sdk_version_2 | sdk_version 3
App1       2              1               0
App2       0              1               1
```

Further more, I may want to include a `WHERE` clause to exclude app_names that had *any* requests from a certain sdk_version.

Is there an easy way to pull this off in SQL?

Comment: (1) PrestoDB over Hive table? (2) This representation make no sense unless you know all the sdk versions in advance. How about map(key-value)?

Comment: (1) PrestoDB (2) Could you elaborate? There are a finite number of SDK versions (perhaps 10-15).

Comment: Let me reply with a question. What are you trying to gain from this pivoting? what not just group by `app_name` and `sdk_version` and count the occurrences?

Comment: I suppose I want to be able to use the columns in a WHERE clause too - so I might want to have the DB returns apps that have no requests from a certain SDK version. If I used a GROUP BY on both `app_name` and `sdk_version` and used the same WHERE, I'd only be excluding the rows for the specific sdk_version

Comment: Querying on non-stable columns (sdk can be added and removed) is a very bad practice .There are various solutions for this, here are two: (1) have 2 lists. 1st list - all applications. 2 list the GROUP BY we are talking about. look for applications with specific sdk version in the 2nd list and subtract it from the 1st list. (2) Generate a table with all applications and  sdk versions. Do a LEFT JOIN on the GROUP BY we talked about. Now you can search for zero occurrences of an sdk for an application